# Add entry to the list of abbreviations but not to the index

Tags: indexing, acronyms, glossaries-extra

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[xindy,abbreviations,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{dualindex}{true}
\newabbreviation{html}{html}{hypertext markup language}
\newabbreviation{ac}{ac}{ante correctionem}

\begin{document}
\gls{html}
\glsadd{ac}
\printglossaries
\printindex
\end{document}
```

I would like to suppress the indexing of `ac`, but keep it in the list of abbreviations. Currently it appears in the index under the page in which `\glsadd` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign it a different category attribute (that doesn't have the `dualindex` attribute set). For example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[xindy,abbreviations,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{dualindex}{true}
\newabbreviation{html}{html}{hypertext markup language}
\newabbreviation[category=nondual]{ac}{ac}{ante correctionem}

\begin{document}
\gls{html}
\glsadd{ac}
\printglossaries
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Since there's no abbreviation style explicitly set for this category, it will fall back on the style for the `abbreviation` category.

[image: Abbreviations ac ante correctionem html hypertext markup language]

[image: Index html, 1]